# Runtime dependency configurations for Wildfly application server

Tags: java, dependencies, runtime, wildfly, classloader

What is the best way to load runtime dependencies for a Wildfly application? I have experience with Websphere Application Server where there is a server.xml and libraries.xml file. In the libraries.xml you define libraries which are basically logical definitions of applications and their interdependencies. For instance the library "payments" might have several JARs/projects defined: "credit-card.jar", "payment-auth.jar", etc. These make it so the classes in credit-card.jar can reference classes from payment-auth.jar at runtime. That is to say that the built classes from payment-auth remain in payment-auth, but are loaded up as part of the credit-card.jar's startup classloading.

In Eclipse with Wildfly, I can go into the build path and add projects that are dependencies. For instance, I can go into the credit-card project's build path and add the payment-auth project as a dependency in order to build correctly. Runtime I get NoClassDefFoundError for payment-auth. I can add the Fileset for payment-auth to credit-cards Deployment Assembly configuration, where it literally pulls all of the class files of payment-auth into the deployed credit-card's classes folder, which works most of the time. I get issues for third-party jars that payment-auth is dependent on though.

Is there an server.xml/libraries.xml equivalent for Wildfly where I can load dependencies at runtime, yet keep the dependencies out of the parent project? Or what is the best practice for Wildfly for specifying and loading runtime dependencies?